# Azure Logic App - Unable to create connection to table storage

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I created a logic app on a free Azure subscription and now want to publish the logic app in a production environment. Only now I get the following error message when creating a connection to a table storage by using a shared storage key.

[image]

I get the same error message when i try to create the connection.
[image]

I have the following assignments on my account:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem you have not given permision to the azure storage table, assign access policy as per the below and it will work.

Table Storage Access Policy
[image]

Logic App Connection Setup
[image]

Hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you configured right access key of storage account while creating Table storage connector in logic apps. Please refer below microsoft doc link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage